# How do I repair a marble floor corroded by acid?

Tags: floor, marble

I recently got some contractors over to repair a section of my house and they unknowingly spilt a small amount of acid on my marble floor.

They did not attend to it immediately and the acid corroded the surface of the marble floor.

How do I repair it?

Answer (score 2):

You would normally clean marble with etch spots with hydrogen peroxide or bleach and then repolish.  From the sound of it yours may be more severely damaged.  I would try both on a small spot and see how it goes.

If your marble is actually corroded then you will have to polish until you hit uncorroded marble.

Comment: What sort of compound or chemical should I use for polishing?

Comment: baking soda and water - flooring stores also sell marble solutions.  Also on your "stain" if you see that it is coming out a little with bleach or hydrogen peroxide.  You may need to let these sit on there for a long time.  You can do that by mixing hydrogen peroxide (or bleach - I would do them seperate) with paper towel bits and letting the paper towel bits sit on stain until it is dry - which may take a day or so.  And if something is working keep doing it until the spot is gone.  It may take repeat cleanings.

Answer (score 0):

Corrosion of marble (a form of metamorphic limestone) is not a stain, but rather a dissolving of the base rock.

The solution (if not too deep) might involve surface grinding, honing and polishing in place, but is not a DIY project.  Discuss with a marble installer/fabricator.

Another solution (if the marble tile is available) is to replace the one tile.

Comment: I was assuming they were using the word corroded, when it really was a stain. They might as well treat it as a stain because if it is corroded its not really a DIY unless you can still find the same tiles.