# What Solutions are Available for Marble Floor Etching / Corrosion

Tags: repair, flooring, corrosion, marble, polish

Below is a picture of what some of the tiles that have corroded over the past 25 years of use, look like in the our house.

I read this [QA post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28835/how-do-i-repair-a-marble-floor-corroded-by-acid), however, am not comfortable with the solutions provided, it would be expensive & they would have to remove each slap (they are big stones placed on the floor), resurface then put back in. Is there such a thing as marble filler or even transparent fillers which can fill these
corrosions?

[image: marble floor corrosion]

Answer (score 3):

That's too deep to grind flat.  It's somewhat of a "natural" look, so you could consider leaving it as-is unless the holes are big enough to be a hazard.  In that case, I would look at just filling the holes.

You can use clear resin, which will sort of keep the natural look.  A variation is to fill the holes with a mix of resin and marble dust.  If you can find a small piece of marble of a generally similar color (doesn't need to be an exact match), you can make your own dust with a grinder.  A marble supplier may also be a ready source of dust from other jobs.  That will look a little more like natural patterns in the stone (like the light colored blotches that are part of the existing stone).

When it hardens, you grind the filler level and polish it.  Experiment first to learn how the material behaves, and adjust your mixture to achieve the appearance you want.  Buy a few marble scraps to play with.  You can use a Dremel tool to grind out some holes to mimic the floor and practice on that.  Work with small batches so you have plenty of time to get each repair right.

You can also buy kits for repair of marble and other stone.  They tend to be epoxy with colorants that you mix to match the color, or an acrylic gel that you color.  Here are a few links (there are lots of options that a Google search will show):

- https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-Travertine-Repair-Kit-TRAVRK/203919972
- https://marblekareproducts.com/products/mk-hole-repair-kit-white?variant=553746433
- https://countertopguides.com/shop/countertop-stone-repair/granite-marble-chip-repair-kit
- http://acrylicrepair.com/high-quality-do-it-yourself-marble-repair

Disclaimer: I've never used any of these products, they're just examples as illustrations.  I mix my own.

If it's just a few tiles, you might be able to replace them from a marble supplier.  You won't find an exact match, but you might find something close enough (or what you think is a better match than a few tiles with patterns that don't match the others).

One other thought: If you use the resin and marble dust approach, that material will be almost a tough as stone and you may need an angle grinder and a collection of successively finer grinding heads or pads to smooth and polish the surface in a reasonable time. If you use one of the kits that are just colored resin, that material is much softer. It will scratch more easily, but you will be able to finish the surface quickly with a collection of successively finer sandpapers.

With the resin-only approach, you can put down a shine layer on the whole floor.  There are products like [Pledge Floor Care](https://www.pledge.com/en-us/products/pledge-floor-care-multi-surface-finish) that are a clear acrylic solution that dries to a film. That will get the abuse and you just periodically clean it off and apply a new layer rather than polishing away the repair over time, which would eventually leave dents.

Comment: Wonderful suggestions & a post that gives me hope. I will look into all the options mentioned, particularly the clear resin & marble dust. Unfortunately, we have had it confirmed that to find similar colour marble slabs would be near impossible. Also, I am not keen on the 'as-is' option as this doesn't look nice at all. We have been particularly abusive to this floor and it hasn't had polishing done in 25 years! Last time was when it was made ready for the flooring & polished after the installation. Thank you again for the suggestions.

Comment: @Kayote, I added information on kits you can buy that may simplify the task for you.  For the number and size of the holes, it might get expensive, though.

Comment: thank you for the effort & references. I have bookmarked the links for info. And yes, this is expensive, however, still cheaper than the alternative of slab replacement. The area covered by Marble is approx 2000 sq feet roughly & while most of it merely needs polishing, the repair area is still big. I came across this on ebay and I wonder if this cheaper alternative also means cheaper quality? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Tenax-Polyester-Resin-Travertine-Marble-Limestone-Tile-Hole-Filler-Repair-Kit/172765556521?hash=item2839a12f29:g:5KwAAOxyrM5TIugX

Comment: @Kayote, there's quite a range of prices for available products and I don't know how the quality varies.  There are also differences in hardness, which would be important if it is an area that could get scratched or abraded by traffic, moving furniture, etc.  The demands on walls, table tops, counter tops, and floors are different.  You might want to ask the manufacturer about suitability for a floor repair and ask for a color sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am professionally experienced in stone restoration, fabrication and polishing.
 That stone  looks like Travertine not marble. Its is naturally full of pits usually they have been filled with a polyresin of some sort. 
You can't polish, etch, sand or grind this problem away. It needs to be filled by a professional who can color match and not ruin the stone further. I will not recommend any commercial professional service the few that I know of are not capable of doing this type of job. 
I might try to go to a local high end custom stone company. Not one that only does tile or just countertops. 
A high end custom place  will most likely have a capable person who can help you. 
Don't DIY this or trust some miracle chemical cure it will not work.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, @Pismurf. I can confirm this is marble. A lot of the stone slabs are still without any pits / corrosion, however, unaware, we had been using various cleaning agents to clean the floor.